# Etiquette for deleting your own answers

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, deleted-answers

Is it good etiquette to delete an answer when a comment was made at the same time that either:

- Identified the question as a duplicate
- Already answered the question
- Some other scenario that resolved the question

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25293227/456814

Comment: Depends. Do you have a specific example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293162/is-it-possible-to-make-height-100-without-javascript/25293227?noredirect=1#comment39418908_25293227

Comment: You're asking about deleting your *own* answer?

Comment: Good question, I did this today. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25290258/3885347

Comment: @Cupcake, correct- my own answer.

Comment: Looks like it belongs on Meta.SE rather than Meta.SO.

Comment: @Powerlord: Why ever should it be over there? Anyway, everything pertaining to SO should be brought up on SO, official policy.

Comment: @Deduplicator It's not specific to SO.

Comment: @Powerlord: In that case, "you should bring up all your concerns on the child-meta, we (mods) will migrate if it should be neccessary", still applies. (AFAICT, such migrations are deemed superfluous just about always.)

Comment: @Deduplicator In this case, it was the reason given for a Close vote, which apparently appears as a comment.  In retrospect, I should have flagged it instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the post is a duplicate then you need to compare your answer with those of the duplicate question.  Does it add value on top of those answers?  If you posted your answer to the duplicate question would it be adding value, or is it just a lower quality version of existing answers?  If you think that your answer is adding value then you should leave it.  You should also consider flagging the questions for merging in such cases (or just deleting your answer and re-posting it on the duplicate) so that the content that you feel is adding value can be seen by a wider audience.

If a comment answers the question then you shouldn't do anything; answers should be posted as answers, not comments.  If the comment has a better answer you may consider editing your answer to incorporate it (citing as appropriate) if you want.